# Modify height all ViewControllers in a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, containers

I have a tab bar controller with 4 tabs. Each tab has a navigation controller.

At a certain moment a view (like a player) is added to the TabBarController just above the tabBar items.

How do I make all 4 navigation controllers with their respective views to raise by 40pt?

I've tried a lot of thing, but with no success.

tabBarClass:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: Constants.TAB_BAR_ANIMATION_DURATION, animations: { [weak self] in
self?.view?.alpha = 1
self?.viewcontainer.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:UIScreen.main.bounds.height - (self?.tabbarHeight)! - Constants.viewHeight, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:Constants.viewHeight)
self?.view?.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:Constants.viewHeight)
    }){[weak self] _ in
       self?.viewcontainer.layoutSubviews()
       self?.childViewControllers.forEach({ (vc) in
       vc.navigationController?.view.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 40)
       vc.navigationController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

The last part is the problem. Tried also changing the height of the view, but didn't got to the solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this if created a custom class of the tabBarController like this , but keep in mind background will be black if there is no other ViewController behind the tab

```
class CusTabViewController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 4 , animations: { [weak self] in

            self?.view.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:100 )


        }){[weak self] _ in

        }

    }

}
```

Or in a child

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func dd(_ sender: Any) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 4 , animations: { [weak self] in

            self?.view.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:(self?.view.frame.height)! - 200)


        }){[weak self] _ in

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Tried your second example, but this will raise my tabBar. I need something to minimize the view contained in the tabBar (the view of the children)

Comment: Thank you so much. I used the edited code and put it in viewDidAppear with a check if the view is actually displayed and it worked. The downside is that I need to do this for all the children in all the navigation controllers. I will use this for now, but if you have another suggestion, please do tell. I will accept your answer.